# Verb for the inverse of greet

Tags: verbs, programming

Is there a verb for the inverse of greet, or a synonym verb for greet that has an inverse verb? Everything I can think of is a verb phrase, exclamation, or noun. Salute is the closest I could find, but it's applicable to arriving and departing.

For context, I’m writing a [hello world example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) of a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)) and would like to add a method for the inverse of greet to the class to show classes are collections of attributes and behaviors. As a behavior, the method name should be a verb or start with one.

Comment: To bid farewell?

Comment: Bid farewell is a verb phrase, is it not? The answer needs to be the inverse verb of greet.

Comment: If you're looking for a single word, I don't believe one exists. The closest phrases there are, are "to say goodbye" or "to bid farewell."

Comment: If you are dead set on having them be a matching pair, you are probably better off changing your `Greet` function's name to something else, like `SayHello` which pairs with `SayGoodbye`.

Comment: ... and then you can refactor them into a single `Say` function which takes a string as a parameter, and call it with `Say(Hello)` and `Say(Goodbye)`.

Comment: Hello World and Goodbye World: duh? [joke, but still...]

Comment: If the opposite of 'greet' is 'not to greet' I would suggest 'blank' but it is colloquial and not in the OED. _Instead of greeting him, I blanked him._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single-word verbal opposite of *greet* (as in a host welcoming guests) is [**dismiss**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dismiss):

> **1** : to permit or cause to leave
>   // *dismiss* the visitors
>   // Class is *dismissed*.

In your case, the function name could be `dismiss()`.

---

To add to this, *Hello, world!* would be what was said at greeting, and, for example, *Goodbye, world!* would be what was said at dismissal.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you are saying when you are seeing people off is a ***valedictory***, and the action itself is called a ***valediction***:

> **[valedictory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valedictory)** *n.*  an address or statement of farewell or leave-taking
>
> **[valediction](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valediction)** *n.* an act of bidding farewell
> *<sub>definitions from m-w.com</sub>*

One would think, therefore, that the verb form is *valedict*.  This, unfortunately, is not listed in any dictionary that I can find.
However, it being for a programming exercise, you are free to use anything that you want.  (Indeed, that's why "help with naming things in programs" is explicitly off-topic.)  And *valedict* is clearly and obviously appropriate (if you are familiar with your Latin roots, at least: *vale* = 'goodbye', *dict* = 'speak').

Comment: As a bonus, to make your actions feel more like a matching pair, you should change your "Greet" function to "Salutate".

Answer (score 1):

In your context "To greet" is to say "Hello" to someone entering your presence (your locality). The opposite would be to wish someone farewell as they leave. This would be saying "Goodbye" or "Farewell".

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes of naming a programming procedure, you probably don't have to be too grammatically correct. Maybe smashing a phrase together - like "sendoff" - would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The only terms that comes to my mind:

- "Part", which is listed as [an archaic meaning by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/part) but is a transitive verb like "greet." "Parting" and "parted" are both still in common use, but "greeting" and "greeted" are both more common than "greet", too. I think "part" only comes to my mind because of [the IRC PART command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_Relay_Chat_commands#PART) for leaving a chat room.
- "Close", borrowing from "closing" as in a speech or letter.
- "Leave", but the latter connotes actually exiting rather than a farewell or goodbye (similar to "parting" vs "departing").

It would seem to me that while there is a common verb for entering and a common verb for greeting, there are only common verbs for departing or exiting and only nouns and verb phrases for farewell, goodbye, or closing.

I would probably use "close" or "parting".

Answer (score 0):

There can be no historic inverse of greet, if, as it seems to me, greet once meant both, just as much as *good day, sir* can be used for "good-bying".

dict.cc gives *dismissal* second to *farewell* as translation for Ger. *Verabschiedung*. I don't even know in which context they see it, but it already shows some negative connotation. We see Icelandic *græta* "to make (someone) cry, drive to tears" linked to *greet*, and the noun *grata* further as "mourn". The association may be passover, funeral, to condole, to pay respect? For *grata* we see PGem *grētaną*, "to weep, to cry" (from the PIE root *ǵʰreh₁d-, "to sound"), whence the verb *grōtijaną, "to cause to weep, make cry; to scold, to address (an issue), to address (an individual); greet", whence e.g. above* græta* and also our English *greet*.

We might see a remnant of this in German *vergrätzen* (synonym *vergraulen, vergellen, verdrießen* and more explicit *verstoßen*) "to alienate, to chagrin, to anger (as much as to make one leave)". I'm not sure, couldn't find anything specific in my usual sources.

Therefore, it depends on context, and the most general context is to *holla*.

You should also consider the many different languages parting greetings that amount to "see you soon/next time" and look for a word for this. I think it might be acceptable, if a bit archaic, to say

> he parted with a greet

and along the lines of *to bid ones farewell*, to say

> to greet ones parting

But of course that's not idiomatic, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

We see the same in-and-out correspondence in military jargon

> to salute, salutation

That would fit, but not in all contexts.

Comment: As a side note, *verabschieden* (chiefly "to say goodbey") also means "(of a law) to adopt, to pass", that has always struck me as odd, and shows the same counterintuitive correspondence. The stem *scheiden* means *to pass, to cede, divide* (with various prefixes; probably somewhat related to *shit*, as *Ausscheidung* is "ex-crement", or "secretion"), but *entscheiden* "decide" might be the informative relative to the judicial sense. PS: I'm not sure whether *schätzen* "to estimate" belongs here (I doubt it bc. of *Schutz* "protection"), but *wertschätzen* "to esteem*, fit's the theme.

Comment: Another nint might be *ich empfehle mich* as salute (literally "I recommend myself). *to commend oneself* does exist, but I don't know of the meaning or context.